# How do you do Diablo III boss runs?

Tags: diablo-iii

As waypoints aren't carried over from game to game as in *Diablo II*, how do you start a new *Diablo III* game to run a particular boss, or just grind on higher level minions near the end of the act?

It's pretty easy to blitz the early quests, but is there a way to just skip it entirely?

Comment: Of note is that monotonous boss runs are going to be mechanically discouraged at maximum level, in favor of choosing areas to explore for champion monster packs and longer game sessions. For more information, search for "Nephalem Valor."

Answer (score 14):

At the character selection screen, use the "Change Quest" button, just under "Start/Resume Game".  There you can select at what stage along the quest chain to start.

For example, in the beta if you just want to kill the Skeleton King again, select the final part in Act I ("Reign of the Black King"), and the final step ("The Royal Crypts"), then hit "Select Quest" and begin your game.

[image]

Comment: It's worth noting that if you start somewhere other than the beginning of a quest, you won't get random party members (if it's a public game). This is because the same granular quest selection menu doesn't exist for joining public games.